# Deploy and hosting blazor wsam with individual accounts

Tags: blazor-webassembly

I create Blazor web assembly Withe individual accounts Option(SQL server).
It works fine on my computer. Register new user and login is fine.
But After Publish and Hosting error 500 appear and app not load.
What should I change during publish? I change connection string to server address and set database user name and password and then Update-DataBase.
But app cannot connect to DB and send error.
Thank you

I tried many ways, but unfortunately I did not get the result.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You Create Blazor Web Assembly with Host and Individual Accounts Option .Then Update-DataBase and Run it . every thing is Good and you can register and login in site.
But When You Publish It and run In IIS webapp can not load and error http500 appear.
Without Individual Accounts webapp run in iis and not problem . but with Individual Accounts Can not run in IIS.